# Z3 might be inconsistent when solving this string problem?

Tags: string, z3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, smt, cvc4

I just encountered a SMTLIB problem in string theory that Z3 might have answered inconsistently.  When envoking Z3 to solve [the problem](https://gist.github.com/hsuhw/ecad1383dfb75af15257b8d447d1cd0b#file-ex1-smt2): with argument `smt.string_solver=z3str3` it returns `unsat`; without any arguments it returns `sat`.

I also used CVC4 to solve the problem.  It returned [a solution](https://gist.github.com/hsuhw/ecad1383dfb75af15257b8d447d1cd0b#file-ex1-model), which seems to be a valid model as I checked it by manually replacing the variable assignments into the problem.

Since I'm trying to do a research using Z3, I would like to know if this is a known behavior of Z3.  Thanks to anyone that could help! :)

**Edit**: I was using Z3 4.7.1 on WSL Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that getting unsat or sat, depending on Z3's configuration, sounds like a bug to me. Check the [Z3 issue tracker](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues) for issues that describe a similar behaviour, and if nothing pops up, file an issue there. Ideally with a minimal example to reproduce the problem with, your current one is rather long.

Comment: Thanks!  After a few checks, I found something similar to my case in the issue list and had earned PR merging.  Would give the master branch a try.

Comment: For future reference, please link to the issue you found. Either by updating your post, by adding a comment, or by adding an answer (you can answer your own questions). You could also consider closing the question (accepting an answer, even yours) to indicate that it is no longer open.